# Better way to create related objects when testing Ember computed property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Like millions of other apps, we have a model that optionally belongs to another.

This model has a computed property that depends on the existence of that parent, like...

```
// some-model

parent: belongsTo('some-model'),

hasParent: Ember.computed('parent.id', function() {
  return Ember.isPresent(this.get('parent.id');
}),
```

(We use a CP instead of `computed.alias` because the association can appear/disappear and `alias` does not observe changes)

All well and good, it works for us. I went to add a unit test...

```
test('hasParent', function(assert) {
  const someModel = this.subject({ id: 1, name: 'Mr. Model, Sr' });

  assert.equal(someModel.get('hasParent'), false,
    'returns false when no parent ID');

  const childModel = this.subject({ name: 'Little Model, Jr.' });

  childModel.set('parent.content', someModel);

  assert.equal(childModel.get('hasParent'), true,
  'returns true when has parent with ID');

  childModel.set('parent.content', null);

  assert.equal(childModel.get('hasParent'), false,
    'returns false when no parent ID');
});
```

Setting with `parent.content` seems really hacky, and I wanted to know if there is a better, more standard way of assigning a model to another. Ember docs are... sparse.

Comment: If you're using moduleForModel, you have [access to the store](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit#ember-data-tests).

Comment: what is your ember-data version? see test at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d12acfc747bae9fd5b926b2abbe32cf8?openFiles=tests.unit.models.some-model-test.js%2C) is working with just `parent` instead of `parent.content`.

Comment: @steveax Ah, missed that in the docs.. I hadn't actually realized models had access to the store like that, thanks - if you want to post an answer I'll accept it, since it looks like the official way to do it

Comment: @alptugd Oh cool, it's nice to see it working there.. We're on Ember 2.10, I'd tried just setting to `parent` and it wasn't happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the comments posted for the question, it is better to make use of `store` while testing models. Hence the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8b62e3399d465cd3d303df964c854552?openFiles=tests.unit.models.some-model-test.js%2C) is probably a better way to implement the given testing scenario. I am putting it as an answer if it is needed by anyone else in the future.